# can't find a design pattern for my structure

Tags: design-patterns

I need the following workflow:

1. A request comes
2. It is being processed
3. if procession result is false, wait for 10 sec
4. If procession result is true or 10 sec has passed, go to 2.

What the design pattern here?

Comment: Does the procession result eventually change although no new request is received?

Comment: You could use a queue system like rabbitMq, gearman to make your bulk processing in the background (i assume you have something big if it's done in 10 seconds). And then when it's finished you could notify the other part by a http api call.

Comment: Yes, it may change depending on conditions. Basically I need to wait while data on remote server will be propagated. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way in rabbitmq to wait for X secs in isolated mode? For example my request should come to subscriber in 10 secs

Comment: Not everything you do must be a design pattern.

Comment: I am asking because I need to choose a framework in case this is the pattern and there's a framework for that. Thanks

Comment: @avalon Not all problem definitions have a design-pattern defined for them. If you are asking for recommending a framework, your question is most probably off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use State pattern with a little modifications.